# Proper Format for In-text Topic (Analysis) Tags for Interview Quotes

Tags: citation-style, formatting, social-science, copy-editing

I am editing a dissertation in the social sciences using the author-date format of Chicago/Turabian. The author was asked by his mentor after his defense to add topic tags to the quotes that came from the interviews he conducted for his research. These are the same tags he used to analyze the data. I have been searching all over the place and cannot find any discussions of the proper format for tagging the topics in an interview. I can think of a number of options (using a simple made-up example):

```
* "I didn't like it." (Negative Assessment)
* "I didn't like it" (Negative Assessment).
* "I didn't like it [Negative Assessment]."
* "I didn't like it." <Negative Assessment>
* "I didn't like it" <Negative Assessment>.
* "I didn't like it <Negative Assessment>."
```

There are more, but those seem the most likely to me. What have you seen? Is there an authoritative voice on this, even if it is outside of Chicago/Turabian? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Someone else might be able to answer your question more fully, but two things occur to me.

### The list

Your description of the problem sounds like something that is likely to arise very frequently in conversation/discourse analysis. That led me to search for journals that publish in the area of conversation analysis, and that in turn led to [a blog](https://saulalbert.net/blog/journals-that-publish-conversation-analysis/) page from 2013 that has a partial list of such journals. Lest the blog disappear, I have reproduced some of the journal names here. You might try looking at some of the papers in them to see how they deal with the problem of "tagging".

- American Journal of Sociology
- American Sociological Review
- Communication Monographs, Discourse Processes
- Discourse Studies
- Human Communication Research Issues in Applied Linguistics
- Journal of Communication
- Journal of Pragmatics
- Language and Communication
- Language in Society
- Qualitative Research
- Research on Language and Social Interaction
- Semiotica
- Social Psychology Quarterly
- Sociology
- Text and Talk

Even if some of the journals are no longer publishing, previous papers are likely to be a useful resource.

### Theses

The second thing worth considering is that very few universities insist on having dissertations conform exactly to a citation style or editorial style (e.g., MLA, Chicago, APA) that was originally developed primarily for publishing journal papers. Dissertation are not journal papers, and exact conformity of a dissertation to a journal style is not only usually impossible, but also frequently not useful. For example, it can be very useful to have footnotes in some psychology dissertations (and no doubt others) despite the general avoidance of footnotes in American Psychological Association (APA) journals.

Thus, it might be that the best course for you is simply to choose a style that makes life easy for a reader (which is possible the top priority in a dissertation ), and is consistent throughout. Finally, given that you are editing for another person, it would be useful to check the stringency of the formatting guidelines published by the examining institution.